# A question related to Laplace equation on pde.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Let $B_R(p)$ the open ball of radius R centered at p in $R^n$ and consider the following problem 
$∆u = 0 $ in $ R^n\setminus B¯_R(p)$ ,$u = c$ on $∂B_R(p)$,
where c is a given constant. 
Find a non-constant solution $u\in C^2(R^n\setminus B¯R(p))$ of
the above problem. I think we get to use Laplace equation.I am not able to figure out how to get such non-constant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Look for a solution with radial simmetry, that is $u(x)=u(r)$, where $r=|x|=\sqrt{x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2}$. The equation becomes
$$
\frac{d^2u}{dr^2}+\frac{n-1}{r}\,\frac{du}{dr}=0,\quad r>R,\quad u(R)=c.
$$

Comment: Aguirre, Could you please clarify me by adding few more steps.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Can you get now the solution?